# How to use Task.Run(...) in Windows Forms? - C#

Tags: c#, client-server, packet-capture

I am trying to make a client-server application using some person's code for console as an example. In the Main function he uses this

```
Task.Run(() => { while (true) ReceivePacket(); });
```

for receiving packets. He sends a packet from one client and receives it with this on another. ReceivePacket is a custom function that does some things when a packet is received.

I am using WinForms and I need to catch all sent packets somehow. What if I put this line in the constructor of my main form? Will it work then? Or should I place it somewhere else?

My app is not finished yet so I can't just launch and check.

Comment: can you show the full method where you are calling / defining the async method also do a google search on `Task.Run()=>` c# msdn examples

Comment: You can put it wherever you want, as long as you only call it once. What kind of client-server application are you building? Wont you need to be able to stop this loop again?

Comment: @Malte R, it's a game for 2 players. And yes I think it must be stopped when one of the players wins or is disconnected. I didn't think about it.

Comment: But if we give you an answer, how will you know if it works?

Comment: @mjwills If the answer is right, then it will work well after I finish, maybe. This application is my first relatively large project, and it is hard for me to plan everything that my program will contain. I write the code in the order in which I think.

Answer (score 1):

You use `Task.Run` for CPU bound operation and not for network call. Refer [this blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html) from Stephen Cleary. If you need to make a network call (client-server) using `Task.Run` is not correct.

To talk to server, you can expose your operations on server through [Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). And on the client side (that is your web forms) call the API using `HttpClient`. Refer [this tutoria](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)l to understand how to call a Web API from client.